# WPF prevent TextBox swallow KeyDown events

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have simple `UserControl` containing a `TextBox`. The `UserControl` also defines some key bindings. However, the `TextBox` seems to swallow all key presses, prevening said keybindings from ever executing.
I have tried marking the `PreviewKeyDown` events Handled and not Handled, but it does not not seem to have any effect.
How can I prvent `TextBox` handling selected (e.g. RightArrow) key events allowing them to bubble up to its parent `UserControl`?

```
<UserControl>
    <UserControl.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Key="Right" Command="{Binding TestCommand}"/>
    </UserControl.InputBindings>
    <Grid>
        <TextBox Text="Foo" PreviewKeyDown="TextBox_PreviewKeyDown"
                 FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding Path=., RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>

public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    private ICommand _testCommand;
    public ICommand TestCommand => _testCommand ?? (_testCommand = new RelayCommand(() =>
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Success!");
    }));

    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }

    private void TextBox_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Right)
            e.Handled = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why `UserControl`? To me it looks like custom control (especially setting `DataContext`), you should rather override `TextBox` to add functionality directly to it.

Comment: @Sinatr it its just toy example: there will be much more content than a single TextBox. However, TextBoxes proven most problematic so I went with that one in the sample code. Then again, if the solution is generic enough, I might be derive TextBox that does not stop those events. Either works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this a similar problem?
https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/227733/Passing-events-from-child-to-parent-controls-built

In his case it is a textbox embedded in a listview handling MouseDown, but I think the principle is similar.

The main pain seems to be you need to find the parent control and re-raise the event against it yourself.

In response to a - perfectly valid - point about the fact that links can end up broken, here's the important code from the above.  Note: this is dealing with MouseButtons and a TextBox inside a ListView, but the basic principle is the same:

- Cast `sender` as appropriate visual control (`TextBox` in this case)
- go upwards/backwards through the visual component tree [using `VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(control)`] until you find the parent control you are interested in.
- Construct appropriate `EventArgs`-derived class to pass information
- Manually Raise the event on the parent item.

example:

```
private void TextBox_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    ListViewItem lvi = null;
    TextBox tb = sender as TextBox;
    // Get a reference to the parent ListViewItem control
    DependencyObject temp = tb;
    int maxlevel = 0;
    while (!(temp is ListViewItem) && maxlevel < 1000)
    {
        temp = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(temp);
        maxlevel++;
    }
    lvi = temp as ListViewItem;
    if (lvi != null){
    {
        //Copy over event arg members and raise it
        MouseButtonEventArgs newarg = new MouseButtonEventArgs(e.MouseDevice, e.Timestamp, 
                                          e.ChangedButton, e.StylusDevice);
        newarg.RoutedEvent = ListViewItem.MouseDownEvent;
        newarg.Source = sender;
        lvi.RaiseEvent(newarg);
    }
}
```

It would seem that the author of the codeproject article I linked to is also on gamedev.stackexchange, so credit to [XiaoChuan Yu](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/13964/xiaochuan-yu).

Comment: Thanks, verified it does work but would you mind adding some brief description/example to you answer - links tend to get broken.

Comment: @wondra good point, I've edited this to include example and credit original author